# How to capture the network traffic generated by an applet in browser

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to find out how a java applet in a browser communicates with a server. Is possible to capture the network traffic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org), it can do captures and protocol analysis, so it is probably what you want.

You just tell it to listen on your outgoing network interface, and it will capture the packets and allow you to view them. You will probably want to filter by the server IP, so you don't see all the other junk that is going on at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you could use FireBug (Firefox extension) to monitor the traffic but I'm not sure if it works with Java Applets because applets run in the JVM. Give it a try.